# How can I recover an irreducible factor $g$ of $f\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$, when I know the factorization of $f$ mod $p$, $p$ prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, factoring

I am studying for my exam in computer algebra. One topic is the factorization of polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. With the Lemma of Gauss we can also look for the factors in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. The algorithm we discussed has the following basic idea: Let $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be the polynomial we want to factor and $p$ a prime. We calculate the factorization of $f$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ and try to recover the irreducible factors of $f$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ from the factors in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$.

Now i am confused why this is working at all. In my book there is stated that we kind of try all possible factor combinations out of the irreducible factors of $f$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ whether they divide $f$. Strangely enough this works only if the prime $p$ we selected in the beginning, is selected wisely$(p/2 >$ Mignotte-Bound of $f)$. I absolutely have no idea why under these circumstances i can construct the irreducible factors of $f$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ from these in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is not right always. Take $ f(x) = x^3 - 1$ have two irreducible factors $ (x-1) $ and $ ( x^2 + x + 1) $ over $\mathbb{Z} $ , but $ ( x^2 + x + 1) $  is not irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_3 $.

Comment: That's the point. I know that possibly my irreducible factors over $\mathbb{Z}$ will further break apart over $\mathbb{F}_p$. The question is, why I can recover them from these factors in $\mathbb{F}_p$ when i choose my $p$ wisely.

Comment: @Sen90  recommend https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~hwl/papers/cheb.pdf

Comment: @Sen90 you can't choose p wisely for a arbitrary polynomial, so, first you have to see irreducible factors, then you choose p wisely, otherwise, this is not possible for a arbitrary polynomial.

Comment: Because, whenever you choose p, then we can have always a irreducible factor over $\mathbb{Z} $ , but reducible over $\mathbb{F}_p $